# $\mathbb{A}^1$-invariance of $K$-theory involving automorphisms

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-k-theory

For a variety $X$ let's $K_0(X,\mathbb{G}_m^t)$ denote the Grothendieck group generated by vector bundles with $t$ commuting automorphisms on $X$. Subject to the relations coming from short exact sequence of vector bundles with $t$ commuting automorphisms (The morphisms of vector bundles has to be compatible with automorphisms) plus if one of the automorphisms is identity it is considered to be zero. Is it true that $K_0(X,\mathbb{G}_m^t)$ is $\mathbb{A}^1$-invariant for $X=\mathbb{A}^n$ where $n>t$?

(This question is inspired by putting together the Beilinson-Soulé conjecture plus another conjecture that claims that the motivic cohomology defined by Grayson filtration is unchanged if we switch from direct sum $K$-theory to ordinary $K$-theory)